# Expectation probability question

Tags: probability

[image]

How can I solve this problem? For the 1st problem, I assumed that $E [x] = E [x^2]$, and got $P( X = 0 ) = \frac{1}{3} $

For (b), I got $p = 0.6, n = 10$ so $P(x = 6) $ then use binomial r.v formula.

Am I doing correctly?

Comment: I'd rewrite the question, not include an image. (Just picking nits).

Answer (score 1):

In the first question $E(X)=E(X^2)=p=P(X=1)$ so $V(X)=p-p^2$

$$ p=0,\text{or}  p=\frac{2}{3}$$

$$P(X=0)=1,or,P(X=0)=1/3$$

$E(X)=P(X=1).1+P(X=0).0=p.1+(1-p).0$

$E(X^2)=P(X=1).1^2+P(X=0).0^2=p.1+(1-p).0$